# The Ropsten bootnodes of the Eth Foundation are down, can anybody share any other?

Tags: ropsten, bootnodes

Running geth in verbose 5 mode, I get this:

```
TRACE[01-11|12:45:26] Dial task done                           task="discovery lookup"
TRACE[01-11|12:45:26] Skipping dial candidate                  id=6ce05930c72abc63 addr=13.84.180.240:30303 err="recently dialed"
TRACE[01-11|12:45:26] New dial task                            task="discovery lookup"
TRACE[01-11|12:45:29] Starting bonding ping/pong               id=6ce05930c72abc63 known=false failcount=0 age=421020h45m29.948607054s
TRACE[01-11|12:45:29] Starting bonding ping/pong               id=20c9ad97c081d633 known=false failcount=0 age=421020h45m29.948655691s
TRACE[01-11|12:45:29] >> PING/v4                               addr=13.84.180.240:30303 err=nil
TRACE[01-11|12:45:29] >> PING/v4                               addr=52.169.14.227:30303 err=nil
DEBUG[01-11|12:45:30] No discv4 seed nodes found 
TRACE[01-11|12:45:30] Dial task done                           task="discovery lookup"
TRACE[01-11|12:45:30] Skipping dial candidate                  id=20c9ad97c081d633 addr=52.169.14.227:30303 err="recently dialed"
TRACE[01-11|12:45:30] New dial task                            task="discovery lookup"
TRACE[01-11|12:45:33] Starting bonding ping/pong               id=6ce05930c72abc63 known=false failcount=0 age=421020h45m33.955656378s
TRACE[01-11|12:45:33] Starting bonding ping/pong               id=20c9ad97c081d633 known=false failcount=0 age=421020h45m33.955745485s
TRACE[01-11|12:45:33] >> PING/v4                               addr=13.84.180.240:30303 err=nil
TRACE[01-11|12:45:33] >> PING/v4                               addr=52.169.14.227:30303 err=nil
```

The command I use to start geth is this one:

```
geth --testnet --rpc --fast --bootnodes "enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303,enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303"  --verbosity 5
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opening `geth attach` and adding some peers manually solved the problem for me.
List of peers-

```
admin.addPeer("enode://0b64924d478abaf6900ffed857dc066b29e6a9498c8a6604a159555bd08fe1ccf3c2cefdbd625b0e7cf93b49c3cc6d6e412a5cde92b4a7d2b8bfd6f10d56511e@136.144.129.222:30303");
admin.addPeer("enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303");
admin.addPeer("enode://4fee548ed37a0aa07101479f0fb8672573b1396b100869eb8a6db77e05b8780293376c0bdd8ed41bfb503e2df20b0702c7b61ff795d9aa3eedf9d70b952643eb@34.195.230.169:30303");
admin.addPeer("enode://5b190dc2848404a46ac47413c35e68e73fd5e4eb4fd681ed511ef3280d47169e703990ecd4e67a3c1eaa4e4788d56d182b3c62f32628bcc9fc772f6568ffc19e@104.236.178.16:30303");
admin.addPeer("enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303");
admin.addPeer("enode://72c074af1e24caaa6904503fa88c3ef2881d319bebb32dbe8282f4be3dab07ffd873970642a5ca7d8f03e3e14b8aea080811828c5ffbd183c94778ef53c904e2@188.214.30.138:30303");
admin.addPeer("enode://a9e72b8b22f5f5ca858588a378af9f2214ac81f65e53b93e0e2bf00e6d36d353ad71a6f28b916155548922cf14401e4ab2950ec2a7a6870a512890e214dcbc76@139.59.155.74:30303");
admin.addPeer("enode://c86ed8addd5f8356e4a3aad415805feb39e0e0e36903be1968bc71abbbd6612437454277cbf39915e3ebf3b9804e7f86644b68e115d56866d4744b69ed67bbc4@173.199.118.174:30303");
admin.addPeer("enode://e8e493e5f11b4275211259e6f86b24b9786f61667fabdd8be4bd9dd26a39083b38bad3f2a443cd968bbf1a87496d62f92a1d4788168b1891b02d35d9d9787065@107.21.14.206:30303");
```

Source- https://gist.github.com/rfikki/ec233552af9f71eb9a00f6cbc4dd7b0d

**Edit**- I don't know how and from where, but this guy keeps the latest peers list for all ethereum networks- https://gist.github.com/rfikki
Please go through these gists if above mentioned peers doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I had to search for such peers addresses and it wasn't easy.

Comment: Also for anyone experiencing the same problem - check it if the latest blocks on your chain have the same hashes as the public. Sometimes your geth node can go on an invalid chain and it wouldn't start to resync later unless you delete the whole chaindata directory.

Comment: If you don't want to delete the whole directory, and you know on which block your chain forked, you can set head to that block using `debug.sethead(blocknumber)`. It is a lot of manual work though.